# An inequality in residuated lattices?

Tags: inequality, lattice-orders

Let $(A;\wedge,\vee,\odot,\rightarrow_l,\rightarrow_r,0,1)$ be a residuated lattice. Does the inequality $((x\rightarrow_l a)\rightarrow_r a)\odot((y\rightarrow_l a)\rightarrow_r a)\leq (((x\odot y)\rightarrow_l a)\rightarrow_r a)$ hold? If this inequality does not hold is there a counterexample for it?